# Libraries not loading when running Rscript from PHP

Tags: php, r, exec, rscript

I am trying to run an R script from PHP.

My PHP file looks like this:

```
exec("Rscript fig_lollipop.r");
```

And my R script looks like this:

```
library('RPostgreSQL')
#more goes code here...
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in library("RPostgreSQL"):There is no package called 'RPostgreSQL'
```

I have attempted searching for common answers to this, and I think it might be related to the www-data user, but I'm really not sure.  The R script works fine when running from the terminal.

Thanks in advance for any help!
RC

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am working on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Can you change your script to show the value of `.libPaths()` for that session so that you know the web user can see the package? Do they have permissions to read those files?

Comment: The `.libPaths()` command in the terminal revealed an additional folder (where all the relevant packages are stored), as compared to `.libPaths()` from the web app.  I copied the needed packages to a folder listed in `.libPaths()` from the web app, and now everything works.  Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran the `.libPaths()` command in the terminal, and discovered an additional folder (where all of the relevant packages are stored), as compared to the `.libPaths()` command run from the web app.  I ended up copying relevant packages to a folder listed in the web app `.libPaths()`, and everything works now.

Thanks to "MrFlick" for the advice!  I'm a newbie to this stuff, and thought that packages were installed for all users.